# rails: Is it possible that my receiver_id failling to be picked?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am implementing a messaging solution for my rails app, I keep get the following error.

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation - ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
```

LINE 1: ...rsations" WHERE ((sender_id = 3 AND receiver_id = '') OR (se...

```html
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    if current_user.id == message_params[:receiver_id]
      redirect_to request.referrer, alert: "You cannot send a message to yourself"
    end

    conversation = Conversation.where("(sender_id = ? AND receiver_id = ?) OR (sender_id = ? AND receiver_id = ?)", 
                                      current_user.id, message_params[:receiver_id],
                                      message_params[:receiver_id], current_user.id
                                    ).first
    if !conversation.present?
      conversation = Conversation.create(sender_id: current_user.id, receiver_id: message_params[:receiver_id])
    end 

    @message = Message.new(user_id: current_user.id, 
                          conversation_id: conversation.id,
                          content: message_params[:content] 
                        )
      if @message.save
        format.html { redirect_to request.referrer, notice: 'Message was successfully sent.' }
      else
        format.json { render json: request.referrer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Conversation model.

```html
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: "User"

  def last_message
    message = Message.where(conversation_id: self.id).last
    if message.present?
      return message
    else 
      return Message.new updated_at: Time.now
    end
  end
  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

That happens because the value you're passing for `reciever_id` is an empty string, but the data type of that column in your database is an integer.

You can use `or` to make the query, but it'll transform your empty string to nil:

```
reciever_id = message_params[:reciever_id]
Conversation.where(sender_id: current_user.id, reciever_id: reciever_id)
            .or(Conversation.where(sender_id: reciever_id, reciever_id: current_user.id))
```

Anyway, you might want to check what you're receiving in order to do the query you're performing. It can be assigning default values, returning early, adding constraints to your routes, etc.

Comment: Thank you, not working. Though I also noticed I had typos with my "receiver", corrected that. I have added my views

Comment: The problem was with my partial, seems I was not passing my variables into the partial, I am still struggling with it. let me post it below.

Comment: But that's totally a different error, isn't it? Did you manage to solve the one you posted in your question?

Comment: I believe though I could be wrong, it's the same error, while I was able to pass an Id, I seem to pass the wrong ID, i.e the ID of the first user on my list of users. I

Comment: Add the logs of that query to your question, before and after trying something new @sam.

Answer (score 0):

Pasting the form directly works but putting it on the partial does not, i.e below this works.

```html
- if current_user.id != profile.user.id
              %small
                %button.btn.btn-outline-light{"data-target" => "#modal_large", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button"}
                  Send Message
              = simple_form_for Message.new do |f|
                = f.error_notification
                = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

                .form-inputs
                  .row
                    .col
                      = f.hidden_field :receiver_id, value: profile.user.id
                      = f.input :body, autofocus: true, label: "Type Your Message Below" 
                .form-actions
                  .row
                    .col
                      = f.button :submit, "Send Message", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2 float-right"
              = render partial: "message", locals: { user: profile.user }
```

This does not work..

```html
#modal_large.modal.fade{"aria-hidden" => "true", "aria-labelledby" => "modal_large", :role => "dialog", :tabindex => "-1"}
  .modal-dialog.modal-lg{:role => "document"}
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %h5.modal-title Send a New Message
        %button.close{"aria-label" => "Close", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
          %i.ti-close.font-size-14
      .modal-body.py-4
        = simple_form_for Message.new do |f|
          = f.error_notification
          = f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present?

          .form-inputs
            .row
              .col
                = f.hidden_field :receiver_id, value: user.id #profile.user.id
                = f.input :body, autofocus: true, label: "Type Your Message Below" 
          .form-actions
            .row
              .col
                = f.button :submit, "Send Message", class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg mt-2 float-right"
```

The specific problem is on this line below.

```html
= render partial: "message", locals: { user: profile.user }
```

Comment: What is your partial filename? It should be`_message.html.haml` and it should be in the same directory as the first view file.

Comment: That is the name of my partial _message.html.haml and it's in the same directory as the view file.